# Impact of friction on a fallen body

Tags: forces, friction

If a body travelling at speed falls to the ground through an arc from a certain height (someone walking who trips, for example), how does friction of the ground surface affect the forces impacting upon the body (treating it as a point mass) when it reaches the ground? How can the net forces on the body and the net vertical impact velocity be calculated?

Comment: Are you asking if someone falling on ice would experience more or less pain than someone falling on concrete?

Comment: In effect, yes. But I want to be able to quantify it.

Comment: Have you seen how when someone falls flat on ice, they keep sliding, but on concrete they don't Those extra forces are due to friction and you _do_ feel them. So the answer is, yes friction does affect the contact forces (or impulses).

Comment: Yes, I know that is the case but I want to know how to calculate the net force on the fallen body from the H and V components of the speed of fall, the coefficient of friction and anything else relevant.

Comment: There is no closed form solution. Only simulation/numerical solution is possible.

Comment: Forget about the falling part, which is a hard enough problem on it own (large angle inverted pendulum), or about that friction (or lack of) causes transitions (feet may slide, or lift off during fall), and focus only on a simple sphere impacting a flat surface. Forget forces, or impulses, what you want is contact pressure so look up Herzian contact theory and re-word the problem to be more specific and less general.

Comment: A point mass wouldn't care - either it's already on the ground or it *can't* experience friction. Now a rod on the other hand...